# Typescript: dictionary whose value type are inferred from key

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Is it possible in Typescript to build a dictionary where the type of the type would be inferred from the key ?

Is it possible to achieve the below behavior in Typescript?

```
interface Foo  {
  kind: 'foo',
  info: string,
  someProperty: string

interface Bar  {
  kind: 'bar',
  info: string,
  otherPropery: string

// I think this might be achieved by using generics
type Dictionary =  { [type in 'a' | 'b' ]: (item: TypeInferredFromKey) => void };

const a: Dictionary = {
   'foo': (item: Foo) => { ...  }
   'bar': (item: Bar) => { ...  }
}
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChnIDWoAJgFzIDkMmlA3PsqDRQM5hSgDmDBr6AWwgAFKOgAO0MAE82HbgwC+uXKEixEKAEJwoORsRDkqAI131GzdHM4gejdGAAW0UROizk7W-eW4ZksgAKtKSALJw4sgAvPoENNZomLzIZlAUOlBKDP6hKAAiwAhgwOggutIxOMgA2gDSTCBEENLoMMF5EeIAuhQAFMCQAhQh4ZH13QCUMQB8yABu6MAkyIo5CGXsyHAUhcWl5VCVsXjxmP2DEMNJ6NPRc9iKADSMaRdDGbp3D8+4a7hAA) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @wonderflame Yes, this would work and now that I see your answer,  it's obvious for me. I was actually wondering if it was possible to avoid using the TypeMap ( I guess it's not ) . But this is good for my use case. Thanks !

Comment: There is no way to convert the string to the type with the same name :(. WIll write an answer in a bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to convert `string` to the type with the exact same name, thus we will need to store some dictionary where keys are the strings(name of the types) and values are the types themselves:

```
interface Foo {
  kind: 'foo';
  info: string;
  someProperty: string;
}

interface Bar {
  kind: 'bar';
  info: string;
  otherPropery: string;
}

type TypeMap = {
  foo: Foo;
  bar: Bar;
};
```

Now, simply with mapped types you can create the dictionary type, where keys are the names of the types and values are the functions accepting an item of the relevant type:

```
type Dictionary = { [K in keyof TypeMap]: (item: TypeMap[K]) => void };
```

Testing:

```
const a: Dictionary = {
  foo: (item: Foo) => {},
  bar: (item: Bar) => {},
};
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChnIDWoAJgFzIDkMmlA3PsqDRQM5hSgDmDBr6AWwgAFKOgAO0MAE82HbgwC+uXKEixEKAEJwoORsRDkqAI131GzdHM4gejdGAAW0UROizk7W-eW4ZksgAKtKSALJw4sgAvPoENNZomLzIZlAUOlBKDP6hKAAiwAhgwOggutIxOMgA2gDSTCBEENLoMMF5EeIAuhQAFMCQAhQh4ZH13QCUMQB8yABu6MAkyIo5CGXsyHAUhcWl5VCVsXjxmP2DEMNJ6NPRc9iKADSMaRdDGbp3D8+4a7hAA)